# How can i repeat bitmap on Android in Java?

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

Greetings fellow programmers, I want to repeat my bitmap vertically on Android in Java. I am making a game right now for Android platform such as Mario and a bitmap which is my background needs to be repeated in X-axis. My bitmap is too large for my screen that's why I only draw a half portion of the device screen. I move my background backward on each iteration in my draw method like below;

```
bgSrcX[0] += 20;
bgSrcX2[0] += 20;   
bgSrc[0].set(bgSrcX[0], 0, bgSrcX2[0], bg[0].getHeight());    
canvas.drawBitmap(tileMe.getBitmap(), bgSrc[0], bgDst[0], null);
```

I would be very grateful if you guys and ladies can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)?

```
Bitmap bitmap = getYourBitmap();
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
drawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
someView.setBackground(drawable);
```

Comment: I am drawing my bitmaps via Canvas. I don't have any views on my game :/

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu You can set this bitmap directly to your canvas too rather then set it as a background to some view.

Comment: I did use on my one layout and caused an error due to thread privilege like below.  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.  It didn't solve my problem but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @YektaSarıoğlu If that is your problem have you tried running it in the UIThread using the runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}); function?